# Flameshot does not work at Fedora Workstation 39

Tags: fedora, gui, screenshot

For Fedora Workstation 39, installed through VirtualBox, was installed `Flameshot` with the `sudo dnf install flameshot` command. Even when the OS was re-started, when through *Show Apps* for the `Flameshot` icon:

1. is accomplished double left click nothing happens
2. With right click appears the contextual menu and doing click at the *Open launcher*  item, after of some seconds, appears at the top of the screen, just below of the clock, a small Window with the *Flameshot Error - Unable to capture screen* message and below other Window with some settings and including the *Take new screenshot* button. If the mentioned button is clicked this (2) case happens again.

If with the Right Click for the mentioned contextual menu:

- is selected the `Configure` item then is opened the expected window
- Is selected the `Take screenshot` item happens the point 2 but without the second window

What is missing? Some extra configuration? Some extra package to install? or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue: [Fedora bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2248667), [upstream issue](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/3340).

One of the recommended workarounds is to run these two commands to grant necessary permissions for screenshoting to Flameshot:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.SetPermission string:'screenshot' boolean:true string:'screenshot' string:'org.flameshot.Flameshot' array:string:'yes'

dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup string:'screenshot' string:'screenshot'
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will try your commands soon as I can.